# Save different table product Prestashop 1.5

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

On Prestashop 1.5

How can I save info to another table?

I have an aux table product called "ps_product_temp" that I'm interested to save some variables of "Product.php" class object that I've created.

On Product.php I have:

```
    public example = 0;


    'example' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'temp' => true, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
```

On SQL I created "ps_product_temp" and there are "example" field for these.

On AdminProductController.php I have the core function "CopyFromPost" that I put this:

> $product->example = (int)Tools::getValue('example'); // get the value
>   from form on tpl

The value loads correctly, but I can't put this on my sql table because on "CopyFromPost" put the fields to "ps_product_SHOP". And makes me this error:

> An error occurred while updating object. product ()

Hoy can I save these to another table?

sorry for my bad english :P

Answer (score 1):

like previous Prestashop, you must create model follow your table name. and then use object model to save automatically. Or you can create manual save in model and call by your class or admintab